# Simple ViewPager - Single Layout

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-viewpager

I'm trying to do a simple ViewPager from an array of images.

My array is:

```
<string-array name="ot_images">
   <item>"file:///android_res/drawable/ot_100.jpg"</item> 
   <item>"file:///android_res/drawable/ot_101.jpg"</item> 
   <item>"file:///android_res/drawable/ot_102.jpg"</item> 
   <item>"file:///android_res/drawable/ot_103.jpg"</item>
```

My Layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And so far MyPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.farleft;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.left;
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.middle;
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.right;
        break;
    case 4:
        resId = R.layout.farright;
        break;
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}
@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

I've followed this tutorial:
[Android User Interface Design: Horizontal View Paging](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/)

Everything is working fine, but my question is:

How do you use this tutorial with 1 layout instead of 5?
Thank you!

Comment: Please explain clearly//

Comment: you can use @Kushwaha's answer. just replace the text view with the image resource ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to define a common layout say `common_layout.xml` and place it in the container of the viewpager by overriding the `instantiateItem` method.
In the following example i have assumed that you have a TextView with id text.

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_layout, null);
   switch (position) {
       case 0:
         ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("One");
         break;
       case 1:
         ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Two");
         break;
       case 2:
         ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Three");
         break;
       case 3:
         ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Four");
         break;
       case 4:
         ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Five");
         break
     }

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
 }
```